# Replacing an element in array is replacing every element in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array that I want to search and just place one item that matches in a search like so:-

Array and code example :

```js
const test = [
  { id: 0, title: 'test1', seen: false },
  { id: 1, title: 'test2', seen: false },
  { id: 2, title: 'test3', seen: true },
];
```

I need to be able to search the test array for the ID:2 and set it to 'seen:true'

I have tried :

```js
const [testarray, testTestArray] = usestate(test);
const checkID = 2;

const updateStatus = (checkID) => {

    const new_data = testarray.data.map(id => {
    if (id === checkID) {
      // No change
      return id;
    } else {
      return {
        ...id,
        seen: true,
      };
    }
  });

  setTest(new_data);
```

I have played with it in different ways and the closest I have got is changing all of them to 'seen: true'?

What am I not getting here?

Thanks

Comment: even if you named the variable `id`, that variable is actually an item of the array. You should access the `id` property of that object in order to perform the comparison. Something like `if (id.id === data.checkID)`

Comment: Your array example is named `test` which is not actually used anywhere, you're calling a function named `setTest` that is not defined anywhere, you're passing it a variable named `new_data` that is not defined anywhere, and the function refers to a variable `test_data` that is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I have updated code slightly and even if I check like you said '===' I still get same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking `id` with the `checkID` which will never be equal because you are comparing `object`(each individual object in array) with `number`.

You have to compare it with `id.id` or for better naming convention `obj.id` with `checkID`.

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-pine-ntn36t?file=/src/App.js)

```js
  const updateStatus = (checkID) => {
    console.log(checkID);
    const new_data = testarray.map((obj) => {
      if (obj.id === checkID) {
        return {
          ...obj,
          seen: true
        };
      } else {
        return obj;
      }
    });

    setTestArray(new_data);
  };
```

---

You can more simpliyfy it as:

```js
  const updateStatus = (checkID) => {
    const new_data = testarray.map((obj) => ({
      ...obj,
      seen: obj.id === checkID ? true : obj.seen
    }));

    setTestArray(new_data);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix that:

```
const [array, setArray] = useState(test);
const checkID = 2;

const updateStatus = (checkID) => {
  const new_data =  array.map(item => {
    // here was the major mistake
    if (item.id === checkID) {
      return {
        ...item,
        seen: true,
      };
    } else {
      // No change
      return item;
    }
  });
  setArray(new_data);
}
```

Errors were:

- Using different names.
- not using the item property but the item itself in comparison.
- if-else blocks were inverted respect to what is asked.

I hope everything is understood.